# Callback class member

Tags: ros, c++, callback, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
Is it possible to use a member class method as a callback? Something like this:

```
void Node::chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg){
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

void Node::Subscribe(){
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("alives", 1000, &Node::chatterCallback, this);
}
```

At the examples (http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/UsingClassMethodsAsCallbacks) , I've seen:

```
Listener listener;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &Listener::callback, &listener);
```

But I don't want to instantiate another object. I've the callback function as a method in my class.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66082/callback-class-member/) by [Verane](https://answers.ros.org/users/5216/verane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-27**:
I think it is possible, as I do it with Python. Just try and see. Just found this question : answers.ros.org/question/64446/problem-using-class-function-as-callback/ which might include the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your question, it seems like you already know that it's possible to use class methods as callbacks.  Your question seems to be, more specifically: "Is it possible to use methods of the current class object from which subscribe() is called?".  In other words, can you pass in `this` as the class object parameter to the subscribe call.

The answer to *that* question is also *yes*.  ROS doesn't care where the object comes from.  The turtlesim `turtle` class creates a subscriber with a local member-function callback, just as you are asking about (see [here](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/turtlesim/html/turtle_8cpp_source.html#l00054)).

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4